# Pushing a javascript object into another javascript object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to merge two javascript sets into one. I am trying to put the products javascript object into the Quotes attribute of the solution object. So the end result should be the SolutionProducts object.

```
$scope.Products = {  
"id":"",
"attributes":{  
  "term":"36"
},
"groups":[  
  {  
     "products":[  
            // list of products
     ]
  }
]
}

$scope.Solution = {  
"SolutionID":"",
"Quotes":[  

]
}



$scope.SolutionProducts = {  
"SolutionID":"",
"Quotes":[  
  {  
     "id":"",
     "attributes":{  
        "term":"36"
     },
     "groups":[  
        {  
           "products":[  
                  // list of products
           ]
        }
     ]
  }
]
}
```

I tried to use the push function but it didn't work

```
$scope.SolutionProducts = $scope.Solution.Quotes[0].push($scope.Products.products);
```

Comment: The return value of `Array.prototype.push` is not the new array, but the number of elements.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with JSON, which is a data serialization format.  You are simply talking about javascript objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple mistake: you are assigning the return value of the `Array.push` method to your variable `$scope.SolutionProducts`. Instead do this:

```
$scope.Solution.Quotes.push($scope.Products);
$scope.SolutionProducts = $scope.Solution;
```

Note that `$scope.Solution` and `$scope.SolutionProducts` will have the same reference, meaning you actually don't need to have the `$scope.SolutionProducts` variable and can just go on with `$scope.Solution`.

Answer (score 1):

@MVP brings up one key issue with your code: you simply want to pass a reference of the `Solution` object to the `SolutionProducts` object. With your current code, you are setting `$scope.SolutionProducts` to the return value of the `push()` function, which actually returns a the length of the array as an integer, not the object. (See [MDN's article on `push` for more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push))

The second issue is that you're not actually using `push` on an array:

```
$scope.SolutionProducts = $scope.Solution.Quotes[0].push($scope.Products.products);
```

You're applying `.push` to `Quotes[0]`, which is a *value* in the array, not the array itself. You need something like this:

```
$scope.Solution.Quotes.push($scope.Products);
```

Now you're using the `push` function on a proper array.

Putting both of these issues together, you should have something that looks a little like this:

```
$scope.Solution.Quotes.push($scope.Products);
$scope.SolutionProducts = $scope.Solution; //sets SolutionProducts to Solution reference
```